# Logarithmic integral function $\mathrm{li}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was reading the book of Zorich "Mathematical Analysis" about improper integrals and came across interesting question. First of all let me give some preliminaries.

> In the case when the integrand is not bounded in a neighborhood of one
> of the interior points $\omega$ of the closed interval $[a,b]$, we set
>  $$\int \limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx:=\int \limits_{a}^{\omega}f(x)dx+\int
>  \limits_{\omega}^{b}f(x)dx,\quad \quad (6.81)$$ requiring that both of
> the integrals on the right-hand side exist.
>
> Besides (6.81), there is a second convention about computing the
> integral of a function that is unbounded in a neighborhood of an
> interior point $\omega$ of a closed interval of integration. To be
> specific, we set $$\text{PV}\int \limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx:=\lim
>  \limits_{\delta\to 0+}\left(\int
>  \limits_{a}^{\omega-\delta}f(x)dx+\int
>  \limits_{\omega+\delta}^{b}f(x)dx\right),\quad \quad (6.82)$$ if the
> limit on the right-hand side exists.
>
> **Example 21.** The precise definition of the logarithmic integral can now be written
> as  $$\mathrm{li}(x) =
>      \begin{cases}
>      \int \limits_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}, & \text{if }0<x<1, \\
>      \mathrm{PV} \int \limits_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}, & \text{if }1<x.
>      \end{cases}$$
>     In the last case the symbol PV refers to the only interior singularity on the interval $(0,x]$, which is located at $1$. We
> remark that in the sense of the definition in formula $(6.81)$ this
> integral is not convergent.

I would like to clarify some questions related with the $\mathrm{li}\ (x)$.

1. So as far as I inderstand $\mathrm{li}(x)$ is a real-valuable function defined on $(0,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$, right?
2. For $x\in (0,1)$ we define $\mathrm{li}(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}$. Do we consider this integral as improper or definite? The integrand $\frac{1}{\ln t}$ is not defined at $0$ but since $\lim \limits_{t\to 0+}\frac{1}{\ln t}=0$, then we can define $\frac{1}{\ln 0}=0$ to make it continuous on $[0,x]$. So is it improper or definite integral?
3. Why $\mathrm{li}(x)$ is not defined at 1? What if we set $\mathrm{li}(1):=\int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\ln t}$? But I realised that this integral is divergent since $\ln t\sim t-1$ as $t\to 0$. Is that argument correct?
4. I understand that if $x>1$, then $\int \limits_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}$ is divergent in the sense of formula $(6.81)$ since integral $\int \limits_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}$ is divergent since $\ln t\sim t-1$ as $t\to 0$. But why does $ \mathrm{PV} \int \limits_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}:=\lim \limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}\bigg(\int \limits_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{dt}{\ln t}+\int \limits_{1+\epsilon}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}\bigg)$ exist?

I'd be very grateful if someone can answer my questions!

Comment: Not sure if others on Math SE agree, but I think this post could get more attention and engagement if you keep it focused to one or two of your questions.

Comment: @AlannRosas, I don't think so. I asked 4 questions on the same topic and to two of them I alredy answered and just want to check my argument. So there is no reason to open multiple topics!

Comment: for 4 one has that $\log$ changes sign at $1$ so the infinities at $1$ cancel out when we do the PV; to prove this rigorously one does the usual trick of showing that $1/\log t -1/(t-1)$ is integrable near $1$ and then checking that PV of $\int 1/(t-1)$ exists (near $1$) which is a direct computation

Comment: @Conrad, I was wondering can you give a separate answer with details? I am not familiar with this trick and I'd be very grateful if you can do that, please!

Comment: done as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per request we need to show that for $x>1$:

$$\mathrm{PV} \int \limits_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}:=\lim \limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}\bigg(\int \limits_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{dt}{\ln t}+\int \limits_{1+\epsilon}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}\bigg)$$ exists

First noting that $\int \limits_{0}^{c}\frac{dt}{\ln t}+\int \limits_{1+d}^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}$ exist for all fixed $0<c<1, 1<1+d<x$, it is enough to show that

$$\mathrm{PV} \int \limits_{c}^{1+d}\frac{dt}{\ln t}:=\lim \limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}\bigg(\int \limits_{c}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{dt}{\ln t}+\int \limits_{1+\epsilon}^{1+d}\frac{dt}{\ln t}\bigg)$$ exists with convenient $c,d$ as above (we will take $c=1/2$ and $d=1/2$ if $x \ge 3/2$, while $d=x-1<1/2$ will do otherwise)

Now with $t-1=a, |a|\le 1/2$ one has $|\log (1+a)-a|\le 2a^2$ say and also $|\log (1+a)| \ge |a|/2$ so $|\frac{1}{\log (1+a)}-\frac{1}{a}| \le 4$ hence $g(a)=\frac{1}{\log (1+a)}-\frac{1}{a}$ is integrable on $[-1/2,1/2]$

(it is actually continuous at $0$ but we do not need that - however if L'Hopital is handier than Taylor series estimates, one can easily show that $\frac{a-\log (1+a)}{a\log (1+a)}$ has a finite limit at zero so $g$ is continuous there when we define it by that limit)

In particular, this means that $\frac{1}{\log (t)}-\frac{1}{t-1}$ is integrable on $[1/2, 3/2]$ so $$\lim \limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}\bigg(\int \limits_{c}^{1-\epsilon}(\frac{dt}{\ln t}-\frac{dt}{t-1})+\int \limits_{1+\epsilon}^{1+d}(\frac{dt}{\ln t}-\frac{dt}{t-1})\bigg)= \int \limits_{c}^{1+d}(\frac{dt}{\ln t}-\frac{dt}{t-1})$$ hence it exists as we take $c=1/2, d \le 1/2$ by the above

So we just need to show that $$\mathrm{PV} \int \limits_{c}^{1+d}\frac{dt}{t-1}:=\lim \limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}\bigg(\int \limits_{c}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{dt}{t-1}+\int \limits_{1+\epsilon}^{1+d}\frac{dt}{t-1}\bigg)$$ exists and by a direct computation the sum of the two integrals is $(\log \epsilon - \log 1/2)+(\log d-\log \epsilon)=\log d-\log 1/2$ so the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ obviously exists and we are done!

Comment: Dear Conrad! Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer! I will take a look at this after my lunch. I was wondering can you give any comments about my questions 1-3?

Comment: you pretty much answered 1-3 by yourself (for 3 the integral as stated is divergent since if we use absolute values we get infinity, hence we need some form of conditional convergence and taking PV is precisely that, for 2, since $1/\log t$ is continuous at $0$, I would call that a definite integral, but it is a matter of convention - in any case the integral is convergent for $x<1$ and 1 is as stated, namely $li$ is defined outside of $1$ as $|li (x)| \to \infty, x \to 1^-$; sometimes for $x>1$, $li$ is defined as $\int_2^{x}dt/\log t +li(2)$ where $li(2)$ is a given constant

Comment: Sorry but I am bit confused with your remark to my question 3. We see that $\mathrm{li}(x)$ is defined on $(0,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$. So I was wondering why it is not defined at $1$? If we define $\mathrm{li}(1)$ as follows $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\ln t}$ this does not make sense because this integral is convergent since $\ln t\sim t-1$ as $t\to 0$. Is that argument correct? This is what I am asking.

Comment: the limit as $t \to 1^-$ is $-\infty$ (the integral is divergent at $1$ as $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\ln t}=-\infty$); note that if you take $f(a)=\int_{a}^{2}\frac{dt}{\ln t}, 1<a<2$, then $f(a) \to \infty, a \to 1^+$ so that is why PV works at $1$

Comment: I think that I understood your proof to my question 4. Really nice and elegant! But I still did not get your comment to my question 3: i know that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\ln t}=-\infty$. But why you consider the new function $f(a)$ and you says that PV works at 1? I cannot see this at all and why you consider PV here. Can you make something like addendum please?

Comment: edited to clarify ($g$ integrable on $[c,1]$ means that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_c^{1-\epsilon}g(t)dt=\int_c^1g(t)dt$ and same from the other side